# Как скрыть данные в js?

Tags: javascript

Хочу зашифровать пароль в `Js`. Все отлично правда в хроме он палится на раз-два через консоль. Понимаю что оптимально решение вытягивать данные из бд, но в данном случае это не подходит. Подскажите решение.

```
var passEncoded = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(ps))); // шифруем пароль
    var msg = {
                "cmd":"auth",
                "login":"xxx",
                "password":passEncoded,
              };
```

Comment: хэшируйте его, а не шифруйте

Comment: Лучше шифровать через бекэнд

Comment: @Duoxx а напрямую на странице не варик?

Comment: @Zevra, если вы будете шифровать, то любой сможет расковырять ваши скрипты и расшифровать пароль обратно. Работайте лучше с хэшами паролей. Тогда сам пароль нигде светиться не будет (как результат, его невозможно будет расшифровать), а равенство хэшей будет обозначать и равенство исходных паролей. Также советую прочитать про соление хэшей - это повысит их надёжность.

Comment: @Duoxx а дешифровать тогда как?

Comment: Проверять хеши.